# What does "this" mean in this program?

Tags: java

I was writing a program, and then I saw this on some website that is using the `this` keyword in this code, and I was wondering what it's purpose, it can process a Jbutton, or JTextField, it can show message using the this keyword, what happened to `getSource()`?

Here's the code

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class TextPassWordEvent extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JTextField textField3;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JButton button;

    public TextPassWordEvent(){
        super("Title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        add(textField1);

        textField2 = new JTextField("Enter your Text Here");
        add(textField2);

        textField3 = new JTextField("Uneditable Text field");
        textField3.setEditable(false);
        add(textField3);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField("Password");
        add(passwordField);

        button = new JButton("Submit");
        add(button);

        TextHandler handler = new TextHandler();
        textField1.addActionListener(handler);
        textField2.addActionListener(handler);
        textField3.addActionListener(handler);
        passwordField.addActionListener(handler);
        button.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class TextHandler implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TextPassWordEvent.this, String.format("Message: %s",event.getActionCommand()));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java this refers to the current object instance.
In the example above, the place where 'this' is used is in some code within an inner class.  If this code used 'this' without any context, then it would be referring to the instance of the inner class.

Java provides the notation of OuterClassName.this as a way of referring to the instance of the outer class that this inner class was instantiated in.

So its simply referring to the instance of the TextPasswordEvent class.

TextPasswordEvent is a container and when calling showMessageDialogue you need to pass a container within which the dialog will be displayed, so the TextPasswordEvent.this is saying "pass the instance of the TextPasswordEvent object" to the showMessageDialogue method.  If it didn't use the qualification and just passed "this" it would be passing a reference to the TextHandler inner class instance instead which is not the desired behaviour.

edit:more info

TextHandler is an inner class that implements the ActionListener interface.  In this interface there is a method defined called actionPerformed.

The outer class is creating various controls (buttons, text field etc.) and then creating one instance of the TextHandler class and setting it as the action listener on these controls.  These controls then call the actionPerformed method when the user hits a button or the return key (depending on the control).

Inside the actionPerformed method of the inner class its showing a dialog (showMessageDialogue) and passing two params - the container to show the dialog inside and the message to display in it.

The message it is showing is including the command that was passed.  This is obtained by calling getActionCommand() on the ActionEvent object that is passed to the actionPerformed() method.  The controls create and pass this ActionEvent object when they make the call to actionPerformed, after a user has done the action (pressed the button, hit the return key etc.).

Edit 2:

Add a new inner class definition for another ActionListener that will only be added to your button component:

```
private class MyButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TextPassWordEvent.this, "This only gets shown when the button gets pressed because I only added an instance of this action listener to button and none of the other components");
    }
}
```

Then back in the TextPassWordEvent constructor code:

```
TextHandler handler = new TextHandler();
textField1.addActionListener(handler);
textField2.addActionListener(handler);
textField3.addActionListener(handler);
passwordField.addActionListener(handler);

// Create an instance of our button handler and add that to our button instead of the
// other handler.
MyButtonHandler buttonHandler = new MyButtonHandler();
button.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
```

Comment: so it means that if for example, I am currently focus or interacting on a certain component, and  I press it , or pressed enter, it will output it's action command, any of those components.

Comment: edited my post to explain more about what the code is doing - you should probably read up on Swing event mechanisms.

Comment: but in short - yes thats right user962206 - when the user interacts with a control and presses enter, the message dialogue will display the action command, whichever component it was.  To reference the actual component that created the event call getSource() on the actionEvent.  You could then compare that to TextPasswordEvent.this.button, TextPasswordEvent.this.textField1 etc. to determine what type to cast it to if you wanted to do more with it. (but you'd probably be better off creating different ActionListener implementations if you want different behaviour for the differnt component types

Comment: is that the case, can you show me different implementation or example about different listener on this example like for Jbutton component?

Comment: bit off topic from the original question, but I've edited my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks!! I finally Got it!! , and you showed me a great way of creating handlers. like Creating different handlers for different components Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking at an inner class. In this scenario, there even several versions of `this`.

A plain `this` would be the instance of the inner class (i.e. TextHandler). If you need to refer to the instance of the containing class, you have to qualify it with the class name: `TextPassWordEvent.this`.

Comment: Yest, I am referring to the upper class, but what my question is, if I  am currently interacting with any of those components, it will return to me their actionCommand value?? like if I click the button, or Pressed enter in the TextField? so the this refers to the any of the instance (component)of the UpperClass? am I right??

Comment: No, this will always refer to the instance of Object and not to any variables inside the object, you dont call this.text you call this.button.text

Comment: oh I get it!, if I click the JTextField and pressed enter it will be this.Textfield.text?? or if I button "this.button.text"??

Answer (score 1):

The use of `this` in the segment of code refers to the active object at the time of construction; ie an instance of the `TextPasswordEvent` class

Comment: soo if I clicked the any of those components, it will return me their value? or the object I am currently focus with??? or it will acts the eventSource of that object I am focus with?

Comment: Yes the three components will respond with something. A message showing the action command of the invoked event.

Comment: soo the UpperClass.this is like saying getSource()??

Comment: Yes in a very crude sort of way. `TextPassWordEvent.this` is a JPanel upon which the message dialog is displayed.

Comment: why JPanel? how about if I click the button?

Comment: isn't it the same? since both of them are instance of the upperClass?

Comment: Yes I  did ran it , it gave me a different result, it gave me "Submit"

Answer (score 0):

`this` is always a reference to the current instance of an object.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

this means you are referring to current context.

which means current context in class TextHandler  is   ActionListener is this

For every event we need a listener to perform action, so in extPassWordEvent event ActionListener is the listener required to fire...........